Is it correct to write "the most cheap"?
Is it correct to say "the sandero is one of the most cheap cars in europe"? or should I use the cheapest? I mean that is not the cheapest but there are other cars that are cheaper...

“The Sandero is one of the cheapest cars in Europe.”  Note the capital letters

If you're concerned about using cheapest when it's not the absolute cheapest car, no exceptions at all - that's the purpose of one of. It confirms that we are talking about one out of a group, not one by itself.

We would be more likely to say "one of the least expensive", since any car is quite a big purchase for most people.

@KateBunting of course there are different implications to both - "The Sandero is one of the cheapest cars in Europe.  You deserve better, so buy a Rolls Royce" vs. "The Sandero is one of the least expensive cars in Europe, ideal for families on a tight budget".  "Least expensive" doesn't work in the first sentence.  It would be the better choice in the second, but "cheapest" does still work, especially if the context is saving money.

I haven't used the capital letters because It was a chat on Instagram...

I didn't use capital letters [.....]. And…? Are capital letters unimportant?

@user231250 From your question, it seems you wanted to know how to word "Sandero is one of the cheapest" or "some other cars are cheaper than Sandero" or are you looking for the degrees of cheap, cheaper, cheapest) Is it correct to say "the sandero is one of the most cheap cars in europe"? or should I use the cheapest?

it is a very informal situation so i can write as i want...

i want to know how to write that sandero is one of the less expensive cars in the eu market...it is not my favourite car but we were talking about the fact that it is the most selling car in europe...

I think ELL should make a rule that every downvoter should give a reason for his action. It would confirm whether it is grammatical or personal. For example, I have received down votes for all my posts. Sometimes the upvote and downvote follow the rule - Monkey see Monkey do.

@Davis13 i want to know how to write that sandero is one of the less expensive cars in the eu market. Even if you change the adjective "the cheapest" to "the least expensive", you can still use the superlative, comparative or positive options. Just replace the corresponding form of the adjective..

i want to write it using cheap...

@Davis13 1. Few cars in Europe are as inexpensive (cheap) as the Sandero. 2. The Sandero is not as inexpensive (cheap) as some other cars in Europe. These sentence conversion are taught in grammar classes. You can find this online.

@Davis13 You can also use "cheap" using compared to - The Sandero is cheap compared to most other cars in Europe.

@PeterKirkpatrick you understand what i mean, thanks: so it seems that i can use one of the most cheap...

@Davis13, No. You can use the superlative with "one of", but the superlative of cheap is cheapest, not most cheap. So it becomes one of the cheapest. But at the other end of the price range we would say one of the most expensive (because here we don't say *expensivest.)

It's not correct.
According to the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, single-syllable adjectives typically take "-er" and "-est" forms (eg "small → smaller → smallest") while multi-syllable adjectives typically use "more" and "most" (eg., "beautiful → more beautiful → most beautiful"). There are of course exceptions to this ("fun" springs to mind) but words tend to be used one way or the other, so with "cheapest" being the idiomatic choice that makes "most cheap" incorrect for the context you refer to.
That said, 'cheap' has other meanings beyond monetary cost and can imply low quality or worth (eg "that was a cheap shot"). Also, 'most' is sometimes used as an intensifier rather than denoting a superlative (eg "that was a most pleasant afternoon"). In those contexts, it might not be so unusual to say something was "most cheap" but it's a bit convoluted.

Another exception: sometimes people say "more rare" (an example in the wild). "Rarer" would also be fine.

The problem with funner was that fun used to be considered a noun, not an adjective. Using funner forces an adjectival understanding of the word, while *more fun" is consistent with regarding it as a noun (as some of us still do).

@Peter Its been used as an adjective for at least 75 years so you must have some miles on the clock. If anything, that's likely the reason it is an exception.

@Astralbee - fun could be a verb, too. I was an early reader, and I distinctly recall reading in my father's local London newspaper, that a London Teddy Boy, accused of some mayhem or other, said to the magistrates, 'We was only funning'.

@MichaelHarvey - "Cease your funning" is a song in the Beggar's Opera of 1728 - but in those days the verb meant 'cheat' or 'hoax'.

@Astralbee, old enough to remember miles, though these days I understand kilometres better. It is only in the last decade or so that I have come across such usages as "funner" and "very fun" which force an adjectival understanding. However this is probably off topic for the current question.

OP's query:

I mean that is not the cheapest but there are other cars that are cheaper...

If The Sandero is not the cheapest there are other ways to convey this. You cannot use most cheap
You can also use the comparative and positive form of cheap.
I. Relative Superlatives..
Superlative: The Sandero is one of the least expensive (cheapest) cars in Europe.
Comparative: The Sandero is less expensive (cheaper) than most cars in Europe.
Positive: Few cars in Europe  are as inexpensive (cheap) as the Sandero.
II. Negative Superlatives..
Superlative: The Sandero is not the least expensive (cheapest) car in Europe.
Comparative: Some cars are less expensive (cheaper) than the Sandero .
Positive: The Sandero is not as inexpensive (cheap) as some other cars in Europe.
Comparative vs Superlative adjectives (when in a group)

We would say/write the Sandero, as it is a model of car (made by Dacia in Romania), not a brand.
